# How to use MediaWiki's api to get the first section of an article?

Tags: mediawiki-api

I want to find the first section of a randomly-chosen page and have it rendered in HTML.

Here is what I have tried:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&generator=random&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvparse

But it keeps on returning a result in user talks and others that I'm not interested in.(i.e they are in other namespaces)

I don't know how to specify namespaces here. Parameters like rnnnamespace and rvnamespace don't work.

I'd prefer that this is a single API call, but if not possible how can I do it in two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played with the [API sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox) and this seems to do what I want:

[api.php?format=xml&action=query&generator=random&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvparse=**&rvsection=0&grnnamespace=0**](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&generator=random&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvparse=&rvsection=0&grnnamespace=0)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a specific article rather than a random page, there's an alternative query you can use, based on action=parse: [api.php?action=parse&page=StackOverflow&prop=text&section=0](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=StackOverflow&prop=text&section=0&format=txtfm&disablepp&redirects)

And since you are focusing on the first section, you might be interested in an extended API method (introduced by the [MobileFrontend extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMobileFrontend), which means it's not available by default on every MediaWiki wiki, but it is available on the Wikimedia wikis), which uses a property called "extracts": [api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&generator=random&grnnamespace=0](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&indexpageids=true&format=txtfm) -- this query actually strips all the fancy stuff (tables, templates, links, images...) and returns only formatted valid text content.